# Can somebody help me understand this more. Javascript selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

How does this work? and what are other ways to do it?

```
redirect = function(sectionName){

  document.location.assign('about/' + sectionName + '/');    
};
```

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the question. I expect this is a language barrier problem, combined with my limited knowledge. Can you rephrase the question to a more targeted objective?

Comment: You will get lots of help...if we can understand the specific problem and objective. Also if this code works or doesn't work and what it needs to do. Right now it is impossible to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by block menu you mean an HTML menu made of other HTML elements like divs, ordered / unordered lists then the response below applies, other than that, please explain in detail what do you mean by block menu

*select* is an object which contains a reference to the HTML "select" tag, so is *options* in the line *var opsArray= select.options;* the code provided by you will not work with block menus.

You have will have to create a function which looks totally different.

Let's say this is your menu:

```
<ul id="list">
 <li id="about" onclick="redirect(this.id)">About</li>
 <li id="news" onclick="redirect(this.id)">News</li>
</ul>
```

your javascript code will have to be:

```
redirect = function(sectionName){
  document.location.assign('projects/' + sectionName + '/');    
};
```

This is one way to do it, there are too many ways to do this. Hopefully I understood your question correctly.